# read local JSON file into variable

Tags: javascript, json

I have saved a JSON file in my local system and created a Javascript file in order to read the JSON file and print data out, for instance. Here is the JSON file:

```
[
{"Titel":"a", 
    "Timestamp":"2017-05-18 22:11",
    "Text":"a", 
    "img":"a.jpg",
    "FullText":"a"
},
{"Titel":"b",
    "Timestamp":"2017-08-08 22:11",
    "Text":"b",
    "img":"b.jpg",
    "FullText":"b" }]
```

Lets say this is the path where it takes you to the JSON file:

```
../news_data.json
```

Could anyone please help me with writing a simple piece of codes to read the JSON file and print the data inside it in Javascript. I am very new to Javascript and need something simple to start with. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript has no built-in method to read files (JSON or otherwise). It depends on the host environment to provide an API for that. What tool are you using to execute your JavaScript?

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes, but I didn’t find it

Comment: @kauthar [You sure?](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=load+json+file+using+javascript)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without jQuery.

First create this function:

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', '../news_data.json', true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);  
}
```

Then you can use it by simply calling something like this:

```
loadJSON(function(json) {
  console.log(json); // this will log out the json object
});
```

I found this by simply googling "read local json file javascript" ([source](https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript))

Comment: *In Google Chrome, links to local files are disabled*! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho In this case, the file would still have to be served from a local web server.

Comment: Exactly. There is no client-side way to load json. And no easy way to conslude that. JSONP is the best way so far but can not load real json files without padding.

Answer (score 3):

### You can use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) in jquery

**First add jquery CDN :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Now set full json file path  as ex :- folder/file.json

**Description:** Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

```
$.getJSON( "JSON FILE PATH", function( data ) {

    console.log(data); //json output 
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function() {
  var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
    tags: "mount rainier",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
        if ( i === 3 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
```

```css
 img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="images"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Did you add jQuery to the project?

Comment: Did you come across any errors in the console?

Comment: i'll try this right now :)