# How to read a local JSON file, from the browser?

Tags: javascript, json

I know this issue has been discussed before, but all solutions i have found are from years ago, and do not work.

What i need to do, is to load some config fields from a JSON file, sitting in the public directory of my React app. Just a static asset, **outside of the build process**

When i try fetching it using AJAX, i get an error on an "Unexpected token ':'". My config.json file looks simply like this:

```
{
    "name": "yoyo"
}
```

It's located in the public directory of a create-react-app program. Is there any way this can be done?

Edit: everything is working, i just had some stupid mistake

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the json you've presented.  You need to show us how you are reading it in and how you are attempting to parse it.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read local JSON file into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073151/read-local-json-file-into-variable)

Comment: Thank you, i just seemed to have some mistake..solved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just import it instead of doing request? 
If you are doing it for any reason, have you tried something like `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my question when I noticed you wanted to load a JSON file from the public directory of your project.

To do this, use `fetch` and load the file present from the `public` folder, then set it for use inside your main component (e.g.: `App.js`).

Here's an example using React Hooks:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [characters, setCharacter] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("names.json")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(character => setCharacter(character));
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Star Wars names!</h1>
      <ul>
        {characters.map(character => (
          <li key={character.name}>{character.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working example using the new `useEffect` hook here](https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-json-with-ease-t0z2v)

[Working example using good old `componentDidMount` here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-browser-xse5t)